# Change value of field

Tags: java, android

i got some confusion in String Replacement. i have string like

```
CustomerEmailID=fake; NavigatePageValue=0; IsCustomerInsertSucess=asdewewew;
```

in this string i need to change value of `IsCustomerInsertSucess` to others. but i am confuse that how can i

i have try with

```
String s1 = "CustomerEmailID=fake; NavigatePageValue=0; IsCustomerInsertSucess=asdewewew;";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("IsCustomerInsertSucess=(.*?);", "2026");
```

but its replace entire field also i need to change value only can you please help me

Comment: the answer below should solve your problem, but please rethink your design. why do you want to replace information inside a string and what format is that? maybe you want to take a look at JSON to serialize/deserialize objects in Android - and please try to avoid string modifications like this. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way (not the smartest) is to change your second line to

```
s1 = s1.replaceAll("IsCustomerInsertSucess=(.*?);", "IsCustomerInsertSucess=2026");
```